# Creating loop in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I a text file that contains names of folders. I'm trying to create a script that will go through the text file and verify if for a each folder name it exist, and if the folder does not exist it will create it with "New" in front of it.

Here is what I tried to do so far:

```
$Cont = Get-Content C:\pro\fic.txt
$elem =  Get-ChildItem C:\pro\
echo $elem

foreach ($elem in $Cont) 
{ if (C:\pro\ -contains $elem) 

{ "there is a match" } 

else
{New-Item C:\Pro\new_file.txt -type file}

}
```

Thank you all!!

Comment: So what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it

```
$Cont = Get-Content C:\pro\fic.txt
$currentFolders =  Get-ChildItem C:\pro -Directory

foreach ($elem in $Cont) {
    if(!(Test-Path -Path ('C:\pro\' + $elem) )) {
        New-Item -ItemType directory -Path ('C:\pro\' + $elem)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So few of the observations, I took it by my own because there were ambiguity on those.

The file is having only the "foldernames" or "the full path of the foldernames"
If only foldernames then are you going to check the folder existence on the same path or in a specific folder. With all these assumptions, I did this:

Considering you have the path mentioned in the file like this:

**File Content**:

[image]

If the Folder is not present under parent path(C:\folder), then it will create the subfolders with the name starts with 'NEW', like :

**Folder Creation**:

[image]

**Here is the code to do that:**

```
    $Cont = Get-Content C:\folder\string.txt
    foreach ($path in $Cont) 
    { 
        if (!(Test-Path $path)) 
         {"The folder in this $path doesnot exist. So creating with 'New' infront of it..."
          $bottomfoldername= Split-Path $path -Leaf
          $parentpath= Split-Path $path -Parent
         New-Item "$parentpath\NEW$bottomfoldername" -type Directory -Force
         }
        else
        {
        "The folder is present. So not creating."
        }

    }
```

Hope it helps.